# CentOS - Process 'ksoftirqdx' Memory Hog

Tags: centos, centos6

By running the 'top' command on my server, I notice the process 'ksoftirqdx'  which is running at over 220%. I have tried to have a Google around and even on stackoverflow. However, I'm unsure of how I should proceed.

I'm new to server configuration, and just rely on the server to run a node.js setup.

Any help will be much appreciated.

CentOS 6.5

Comment: In most cases that could mean your server has a rootkit (i.e. Hacked?) - Did you try and run a virus scan? Try this > `http://askubuntu.com/questions/250290/how-do-i-scan-for-viruses-with-clamav`